# Show a glyphicon in a input checkbox in a label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I have a input checkbox, I did customize is so its a little bigger and looks like a button, but i want a small info icon in the right bottem corner using a glyphicon

This is what i got right now, but is wont show any glyphicon:

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style=""></span>
                        <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="lang[]" value="Vue" autocomplete="off">Vue
                    </label> 
                </div>
```

This wont show up anything. How to fix?

Comment: You are using bootstrap 4, right? Glyphicons were included in Bootstrap 3. Now, you have to manually include some other icon set.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glyphicons and bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845599/glyphicons-and-bootstrap-4)

Comment: Because i thought that the problem was the input, couldnt find anything with that, but now i know that isnt the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to add glyphicons manually, add the following line inside your head tags

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or use an older bootstrap version(example: 3.3.7)